# USB Debugging option on my Android keeps turning on

Tags: android, usb-debugging

Every time when I turn USB Debugging off and restart my Android phone (Sony Xperia X), the USB Debugging option is turned on again. I found the following post:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/how-can-i-permanently-disable-usb-debugging-mode

And an answer suggested that one should "turn the device off several times whilst your USB is connected and just wait for it to stay turned off". I already turned off USB Debugging and restarted my phone five times with USB connected to my computer, but the USB Debugging option was still turned on every time. What else can I try to turn it off permanently?

Comment: Eventually I needed to do a factory reset to solve the problem.